# Should not double count the number of products per customer

Tags: sql-server

We need to get a count of records without double counting the type of product. So, we need to find the list of customers that ordered both product 1 and product 2. When we are doing the count we need to count that 1 record only and not get 2 counts ..(Should not double count the number of products)

Ex: Customer ABC ordered Web Version as Product 1 and Book Version as Product 2 but when I count I need to get the count of customers for Product 1 and Product 2 as 1

Comment: Add data in tabluar form and query you have tried so people can give you an exact answer.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    customer, product,COUNT(*) AS [number_of_product]
FROM
    <table>
GROUP BY
    customer, product;
```

or

```
SELECT
    product,COUNT(DISTINCT customer) AS [number_of_customer]
FROM
    <table>
GROUP BY
    product;
```